Compose: Coil + Clipboard. Как скопировать картинку в буфер обмена?
имеется url картинки
использую Coil и AsyncImagePainter для ее отображения.
могу ли я как-то скопировать эту картинку в буфер обмена, не скачивая ее самому?
потому что единственный вариант, который я вижу:
сохранить картинку в файл. получить Uri. использовать
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newUri(context.contentResolver,"",fileUri))


Судя по доке вам надо сделать ContentProvider в приложении с картинкой. И далее сформировать правильный урл чтобы потом ClipboardManager пришел к вам за данными.
